# Excel Convert Date to yyww

Tags: excel

I am trying to combine these two formulas into one cell to get **YYWW** but I have had no luck. Can someone help me out? Thank You

```
=TEXT(NOW(),"yy")
=TEXT(WEEKNUM(NOW()),"00")
```

Comment: Please show your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=TEXT(NOW(),"yy") & TEXT(WEEKNUM(NOW()),"00")` should do the trick

Comment: Awesome!  Thank You... I was going crazy with all the combinations I tried and nothing was working.

Comment: Although this answer has been marked as accepted, as it works for you in most cases, you might be very nastily surprised at beginning/ending of some years, as this solution does not count with ISO 8601. Check my other answer below...

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware, that you need to get an **ISO year and week**, not an actual year and week information to obtain a correct **YYWW** code!

For example on Dec 31, 2018, the correct ISO week-date YYWW code is `1901`, not `1801`, as the whole week (31.12.2018 - 6.1.2019) belongs to the first week of year 2019.

Refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date for more info on ISO 8601 week date format.

Unfortunately, almost none framework/environment/library that I know, does not include a *direct* function/tool to obtain an ISO year (nor the Excel), so you will need to calculate it manually, according to the position of Thursday in the first or the last week in a year. You may use something like this to get the **correct** ISO formula for **YYWW**:

`=TEXT(NOW()-WEEKDAY(NOW(),3)+3,"yy") & TEXT(WEEKNUM(NOW(),21),"00")`

Since Excel 2013, you can also use:

`=TEXT(NOW()-WEEKDAY(NOW(),3)+3,"yy") & TEXT(ISOWEEKNUM(NOW()),"00")`

Comment: This formula is correct depending on where you'd use it. ISO week numbering has certain applications, outside of which standard numbering is more straightforward and natural.

Comment: But I still think, that the **year** should be according to ISO here, as the pair "year + week"  is used. ISO year brings unambiguous information into the pair. Consider my example of Dec 31, 2018. In _classic_ variant, it would lead to `1801`, which would seem to be at the beginning of the year 2018.

Comment: Have you at least tested your example? `WEEKNUM` for 31/12/2018 is 53 in all cases, except for ISO, which **isn't** default for the function

Comment: Huh! you are right, I tested only the year part regarding the ISO compliance. Thanks for the comment! I have edited my post and it shows the correct ISO YYWW now.

Comment: I'll just add, that in Excel 2010, you can get ISO week number using `WEEKNUM(NOW(),21))`

Comment: That's even more simple, thanks a lot for your encore. Edited my post one again :)